# Unable to access length property of defined

Tags: reactjs

I am setting dynamic class name to `input` parameter. I am not able to check the length of `state` parameter. Following is my `input` element

```
<div className={styles1.col75}>
  <input className={this.errorClass(this.state.errors["name"])} type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={this.updateParam} value={this.state.name} placeholder="Your full name.."/>
  <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["name"]}</span>
</div>
```

Following is the definition of errorClass function

```
errorClass(error) {
    alert(error);
    return(error.length === 0 ? '' : 'has-error');
  }
```

But I am getting this error: Cannot read property `length` of undefined.

Comment: errors is an array or object? what you expecting from this line: `this.state.errors["name"]`

Comment: @hitesh, two things are possible **1.** errors is an array and hence `this.state.errors["name"]` gives undefined, **2.** `this.state.errors["name"]` is initially undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, may be on the load of the component, you dont have any 'error' and hence it is undefined when this errorClass() is called. As it is undefined, you cannot access the length of it.

I would suggest to check if you have 'error' first and try to find out length. You can change the condition like below.

```
return(error && error.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : '');
```